# Are there TPU compatible pre-trained checkpoints for image classification?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

I have found TPU compatible pre-trained checkpoints for object detection but not for image classification.  I'm specifically interested in Mobilenet_v2. I would switch to another network if such checkpoints were available and those for Mobilenet_v2 were not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a TPU-compatible Resnet checkpoint in these GCS files:

```
gs://cloud-tpu-artifacts/resnet/resnet-nhwc-2018-02-07/checkpoint
gs://cloud-tpu-artifacts/resnet/resnet-nhwc-2018-02-07/model.ckpt-112603.data-00000-of-00001
gs://cloud-tpu-artifacts/resnet/resnet-nhwc-2018-02-07/model.ckpt-112603.index
gs://cloud-tpu-artifacts/resnet/resnet-nhwc-2018-02-07/model.ckpt-112603.meta
```

You can use this checkpoint if it meets your requirements. If not, you can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/resnet) to train it yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  I will investigate further.  I assume the network was trained on ImageNet.